# Mechanical Turk CreateHIT via Perl CPAN module works but does not show up in Amazon Mturk UI?

Tags: perl, api, mechanicalturk

I am currently testing the Perl CPAN module for Mechanical Turk:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk

The "GetAccountBalance" method works fine, however, I'm having trouble with "CreateHIT".

The method executes successfully, however, the resulting HIT does not show up in my Amazon Mturk Requester web UI.

Output based on the example on the CPAN page (no errors):

```
Created HIT:
HITId:     2N6Q2SNQQ7Q68M3LN73NV12UAGJS8Z
HITTypeId: 2YBT2HVWAVKI7OL4NQS76Z99Q09FNV
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

The Mturk web UI refers to "Projects" and "Batches", so maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks,

Linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on the "Manage" tab, try clicking on the "Manage HITs individually" link near the top right. The hits you created might be hiding in there.